# Trying to make a program that fixes the code of another program

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that can fix the code of another program.

This is the sample program I made that needs it's code fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (
) { printf("helloworld");
    return 0;
}
```

I started with this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int chr ,areLibraries;
    areLibraries = 1;

    while ((chr = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((chr == '#') && (areLibraries == 1)) {
            while(chr != '\n') {
                putchar(chr);
                chr = getchar();
            }
            putchar(chr);
        } else {
            areLibraries = 0;

            if (chr == '\n') {
                continue;
            } else {
                putchar(chr);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Which is supposed to ignore #include .... in a c program and ignore any '\n' characters.

Before running the program ,I expected this to be the output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
intmain () { printf("helloworld");  return 0;}
```

But the program printed this instead

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
}
```

I've been trying for hours to find the issue ,but nothing seems to fix it.It's like the program thinks that every characters that is inputed after the #include statements end ,is a '\n' character.Does the issue have to do with my use of putchar() and getchar() ,or am I too dumb to find my mistake.

Comment: `&& (areLibraries = 1)` should probably have been `&& (areLibraries == 1)`. May not be the main issue.

Comment: What does "cleaning the code" entail exactly?

Comment: @500-Internal Server Error ,sorry I made this mistake while copying the program.It isn't the main issue.

Comment: @ggorlen ,I basically have to make a program that gets as input a program (as a text file) ,whose code has been messed up.With messed up ,I mean that someone has randomly added these characters inside the program (' ' , '\n' and '\t').I have to look for these characters and determine if they must be removed for the program to run properly.I've come with a solution to this problem ,but I faced a small inconvenience...

Comment: "if they must be removed for the program to run properly" As I see your example it will not change behaviour or compilability by removing those white space. With one exception, the blank between `int` and `main`is needed.

Comment: @Yunnosch The description I gave was a brief summary of the assignment ,there are other requirements I have to meet.The issue is not how to fix the broken program ,but why the program I wrote only outputs the two include statements and a bracket instead of the whole text file ,altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the file you're trying to fix must have Windows line endings, that is `\r\n`. You're filtering out the newlines, but leaving the carriage returns. This will cause the last line to overwrite itself.

Try updating your program to this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int chr ,areLibraries;
    areLibraries = 1;

    while ((chr = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((chr == '#') && (areLibraries == 1)) {
            while(chr != '\n') {
                putchar(chr);
                chr = getchar();
            }
            putchar(chr);
        } else {
            areLibraries = 0;

            if (chr == '\n' || chr == '\r') { // <- CHANGE HERE
                continue;
            } else {
                putchar(chr);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude you are a legend for spotting this ,there's no way I would have found this on my own or anywhere else online.I did create the file on windows to test the program.The professor gave us some sample programs ,but they also wouldn't print on the terminal.Perhaps the professor also made the files on windows.

Comment: Thanks, it was not at all obvious, but your code *should* have produced what you were expecting... unless... ;-)